# Sufficient condition for strict monotonicity of the gradient

Tags: derivatives, continuity, monotone-operator-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function that satisfies the following for some $m>0$:

$$
\|\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) - \nabla f(\mathbf{y})\|\geq m\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|,\, \forall \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n \label{1}\tag{1}.
$$

Under what condition \eqref{1} implies the following inequality \eqref{2}

$$
\langle \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) - \nabla f(\mathbf{y}),
y-x
\rangle
\geq m\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2,\, \forall \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n \;?\label{2}\tag{2}
$$

Please show how you would get \eqref{2} from \eqref{1} if that condition exists. The gradient of any function that satisfies \eqref{2} is strictly monotone. [$m$-strongly convex functions](https://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/strong-convexity) satisfy the condition \eqref{2} always. However, I am looking for a case where one can get \eqref{2} only using \eqref{1}.

Note: for $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|^2$ we can make it work. I am looking for another cases.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ satisfies $(1)$ and is also convex and supercoercive.
Then the domain of the Fenchel conjugate $f^*$ is the entire space $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The condition $(1$) is now equivalent to
$$ \|x^*-y^*\| \geq m\|\nabla f^*(x^*)-\nabla f^*(y)\|,\quad \forall x^*,y^* $$
Then the Baillon-Haddad Theorem guarantees that $(2)$ holds.

Comment: What is super coercive? Also, you are using the gradient of the dual function, how would you get the gradient of $f$ from the gradient of the dual function? Can you please show the steps? Finally, do convexity and being supercoercive imply strongly convexity?

Comment: Notions can be found in the book by Bauschke and Combettes. The gradient of $f^*$ is the inverse of the gradient of $f$. No: The indicator function of the unit ball is supercocercive and convex, but not strictly convex.

Comment: It is not strictly convex, how about strongly convex.

Comment: Strong convexity implies strict convexity.